# the biggest power of input number under 500

Tags: python, function, math, input, while-loop

I'm trying to find the biggest power of input number, that's smaller than 500 but my code is still not working.. What am i doing wrong? Thank you!!

```
n = int(input())
def function (n):
    x = 1
    y = n**x
    while y < 500:
        x += 1
        y = n**x
    return y
print function (n)
```

Comment: To help people better understand the issue, please edit your question to be more specific about how it's not working

Comment: What is desired result for n=2: 8 or 256?

Comment: @MBo It should be 256

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to solve this is to use logarithms.

```
import math

def function(n):

    # If n is 500 then the solution to the equation is an integer and it will not be rounded down 
    # using the following code
    if n == 500:
        return 1

    # Find the solution to the equation and round down to find the largest integer power
    power = int(math.log(500) / math.log(n))
    return n**power
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the result that crossed over 500, you have to subtract 1 from it to stay below 500:

Fix:

```
n = int(input())
def function (n):
    x = 1
    y = n**x
    while y < 500:
        x += 1
        y = n**x

    # now we are over 500 - lets step back by 1  
    return n,x-1,n**(x-1)  # return a tuple of all numbers needed


number, power, result = function (n)
print("{} ** {} = {}".format(number,power,result))
```

Output for 5:

```
 5 ** 3 = 125
```

Answer (score 0):

first compute the temporary `y` value, and return the previous (valid < 500 `y` value) if the new value is above `500`:

```
def function (n):
    x = 1
    y = 0
    while True:
        x += 1
        temp_y = n**x
        if temp_y > 500:
            return y
        y = temp_y
```

The `while True` condition avoids to compute `y` multiple times. If nothing is found, the function returns `0`

A better rewrite would avoid using power function, and would use the previously accumulated result (using integer multiplication, instead of floating point power, which can be inaccurate when the numbers become big)

```
def function (n):
    y = 0
    temp_y = n  # maybe start at 1 ?
    while True:
        temp_y *= n
        if temp_y > 500:
            return y
        y = temp_y
```

this saves the need to use `x`, shorter and more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing x first. Try checking the value after calculating with power before entering the loop. Fixed your code. Added code to handle if you pass 0 as an argument

```
n = int(input())

def function (n):
    x = 1
    if not n:
        return 0

    while  n**x < 500:
        y = n**x
        x += 1
    return y
print function (n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to use a while loop as we can safely agree running a loop till 100 will work for all numbers (except 1 as `1 ** 100000 = 1`) as `2 ** 100 = 1267650600228229401496703205376`

You should not use `function` as there is a built-in named 'function'
You should not start from `x = 1` as you never know when `n` will be 500+

```
n = int(input())

def f(n):
    for x in range(100):
        if n ** x > 500:
            return n ** (x - 1)

print(f(n))
```

If you want all n ** x less than 500:

```
def f(n):
    arr = []

    for x in range(100):
        if n ** x < 500: arr.append(n ** x)
        else: break

    return arr
```

Or a one-liner:

```
def f(n): return [n ** x for x in range(100) if n ** x < 500]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Four approaches: one-step method, iterative one, another iterative one avoids excessive multiplication, binary search to work with very large limits

```
import math

def maxpow(n, limit):
    return n**math.floor(math.log(limit) / math.log(n))

def maxpowit(n, limit):
    x = 1
    while (x * n < limit):
        x *= n
    return x

def maxpowit2(n, limit):
    x, y = 1, n
    while (y < limit):
        x, y = y, y * n
    return x

def maxpowbs(n, limit):
    stack = []
    x, y = 1, n
    while (y < limit):
        stack.append(y)
        x, y = y, y * y
    #here stack holds values n^(2^i)
    #like [2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, 4294967296]  
    for i in reversed(range(len(stack)-1)):
        y = stack[i]
        if (x * y < limit):
            x *= y
    return x


print(maxpow(2, 500), maxpowit(2, 500))
>>> 256 256

print(maxpowbs(2, 1152921504606846997))#2^60 + xxx
>>>1152921504606846976   #2^60 exactly
```